# Replace/Delete characters in NSTextView on Enter

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

I recently implemented the steps for the UITextView in this post: [ios - Replace/delete characters [• ] in UITextView on Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61714083/ios-replace-delete-characters-in-uitextview-on-enter). Now I'm trying to port this over to the macOS version of my app and I'm having troubles translating the ranges from the above post to macOS's NSTextView without getting a crash or unexpected behavior. Does anyone off hand know how to do the conversion to make this work in an NSTextView?

Comment: `NSTextView` ≠ `UITextView`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to make it so if I create a bulleted list if I type something and hit enter, it drops to a new line and inserts another bullet. And if I'm on a bullet line, if I hit enter without typing it removes the bullet, effectively ending the list, allowing the user to type normally.

Comment: Isn't this the default `NSTextView` behaviour?